# Scale invariance for geometry nodes instances

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

Whenever I use the *Instance on Points* node to create instances of an object on a surface I find that the instances will change size and distort when I change the size of the object that I apply the Geometry Nodes modifier to.

I would like to create my geometries in a way that is scale invariant, i. e. the instances have an absolute size and will just change in number when I change the size of the object.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by integrating the object to be scaled into another node tree with `Object Info` and the option *Relative*.

This way the scaling of the object in which the distribution of the points is done always stays the same, and only the size of the surface changes.

[image]

The only disadvantage of this variant is that it is not easy to animate, because with every change in the size of the surface, a redistribution of the points also happens.